# How to pass data between PageViewController and ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

In my app i am using PageViewController which has two different View Controllers. I implemented that it works fine. Now what i am trying is to pass some information from MainView Controller to ChildView Controllers when bar button clicked. I tried using protocol,but it doesn't seems to be working.

**MainViewController**

```
import ViewControllerA 
import ViewControllerB   
@protocol MainControllerDelegate<NSObject>
-(void) passInformation :(NSString*)someInfo;
end

MainController<PageViewControllerDelegate>
```

In
**ViewControllerA**

What i would like to see is accessing the main controller delegate in child view controller and pass information when some action taken placed in  main view controller navigation bar button.

```
ViewControllerA<MainControllerDelegate> // Can't find the delegate saying undefined
```

I am sure there will be a way to pass information between UIPageViewController and its Child View controllers. I tried a lot but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information. Post the whole header for both classes, indicating which one is the parent and which is the child. Post the code in the parent view controller that creates the child view controllers. The trick is when you instantiate a view controller that fills one of the pages in your page view controller, you need to set a property in the child that points the child view controller.

I've been working in Mac OS lately, so I'm a bit rusty on page view controllers. If I remember correctly, you pass them an array of the view controllers they manage.

You'd instantiate each of the child view controllers, set up pointers both ways, and then install them in the page view controller.

Comment: Can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301514/uipageviewcontroller-jumping-to-specific-page-from-tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the MainViewController.h file into your ViewControllerA file?